# Dask, changing column type from second to last

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have multiple CSV's that:

- Have the identifier string in the first column (i.e. `"companyA"`).
- Have a variable number of subsequent columns (for different properties depending on the CSV), often ranging in the 1000s of columns (and 100000s data rows).
- From the second col to the last col, all these properties come
  populated with `x` or `NaN`.

I'm trying to get my `Dask` dataframe to have the identifier (first col) kept as a string, whilst the rest become integers.

```py
df = dd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str)
dr = df.replace("x",1).fillna(0)
dr[dr.columns[1:-1]] = dr[dr.columns[1:-1]].astype(int)
%time dr.head(10)
```

With the above I hit `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'`.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can select first, between and last column and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([dr.iloc[:,[0]], dr.iloc[:, 1:-1].astype(int), dr.iloc[:, [-1]]], axis=1)
```

Pandas solutions:

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select all columns without first and last to integers:

```
dr.iloc[:, 1:-1] = dr.iloc[:, 1:-1].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
dr.loc[:, dr.columns[1:-1]] = dr.loc[:, dr.columns[1:-1]].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've tried that and received `TypeError: '_iLocIndexer' object does not support item assignment`. Is this maybe a Dask v Pandas issue?

Comment: @NoelTock - yes, it is possible. Added another solution.

Comment: Same error it seems, pasting the entire error if that helps:

```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-155edddecd08> in <module>
      3 df = dd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str)
      4 dr = df.replace("x",1).fillna(0)
----> 5 dr.loc[:, dr.columns[1:-1]] = dr.loc[:, dr.columns[1:-1]].astype(int)
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('time', 'dr.head(10)')

TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: @NoelTock - Added solution with `concat`.

Comment: item assignment is not supported by dask for slices